# ModSecurity gives Generic SQL injection protection error

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel, sql-injection, mod-security

I got this error on my Cpanel server. It doesn't happen on every update, just some SQL.

> [Sat Mar 11 03:48:18.409435 2017] [:error] [pid 31376:tid 140202228020992] [client 180.253.119.171] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 500 (phase 2). Pattern match "((alter|create|drop)[[:space:]]+(column|database|procedure|table)|delete[[:space:]]+from|update.+set.+=)" at ARGS:description. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf"] [line "254"] [id "300015"] [rev "1"] [msg "Generic SQL injection protection"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [hostname ""] [uri "/app/marketwatch/edit-listing.php"] [unique_id "WMO50kPhgfkAAHqQRtMAAACP"]

What usually cause SQL Injection error and how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve it using this article:
https://othermachines.com/blog/drupal-modsec-and-post-wouldnt-save

So, the mod_security got a false positive. I don't know somehow it uses modsec rule id 300015 instead of 300016 like usual and caught on false security rule. You can notice the id in `[id "300015"]`. So I edited modsec whitelisting in file `/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2/whitelist.conf` and add this:

```
# Disable generic SQL injection rules globally
# for Drupal content admin
<LocationMatch /node/[0-9]+/edit> #might vary depending your code
  <IfModule mod_security2.c> # This is the important part
    SecRuleRemoveById 300015
  </IfModule>
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch /admin>
  <IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleRemoveById 300015
  </IfModule>
</LocationMatch>
```

Don't forget to restart Apache afterward so it will take effect.

**UPDATE**

Somehow the configuration location changes to `/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec2/whitelist.conf`